# Как раскрыть Collapse при переходе по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, bootstrap

Проект на Yii2.
Имеется следующая ссылка:

```
<?= Html::a(
    'Button',
    [
        'controller/action',
    ],
    ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']
) ?>
```

На страничке, на которую совершается переход, помимо основного контента содержится `yii\bootstrap\Collapse::widget` :

```
<?= Collapse::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Label1',
            'content' => $this->render('1'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Label2',
            'content' => $this->render('2'),
        ],
    ]
]); ?>
```

Как сделать, что бы при переходе по ссылке автоматически отображалась первая развернутая вкладка `Collapse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации `contentOptions` отвечает за открытие вкладки

```
Collapse::widget([
    'items' => [
        // equivalent to the above
        [
            'label' => 'Collapsible Group Item #1',
            'content' => 'Anim pariatur cliche...',
            // open its content by default
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'in']
        ]
])
```

Comment: Окей, как сделать коллапс открытым, мы разобрались. Но как сделать так, что бы он был открытым только в случае перехода по конкретной ссылке и экран скролился именно к этому коллапсу?

Comment: в сторону якорей посмотрите

Comment: а чтобы он открывался при переходе, то с помощью JS добавляйте класс который указан в `contentOptions`. Либо при переходе по ссылке передавайте GET переменную, потом в php уже по условию в нужном месте добавляйте нужный класс в `contentOptions`